# setter on element's value does not work when typing inside the field

Tags: javascript

```
var inputValue;
Object.defineProperty(domInputElement, 'value', {
      configurable: true,
      // wont get fired when I type in input field
      set: function (value) {
        inputValue = value;
        domElement.setAttribute('value', value);
        console.log('value changed', this.value);
      },
      get: function () {
        return inputValue;
      }
    });
```

I could not find a proper event for value changed on input element, so I came up with this code.

The problem is when I type in the input field, the set method wont get fired but it works if I set the value via javascript.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _"could not find a proper event for value changed on input element"_ Tried `oninput`?

Comment: @guest271314 `oninput` wont get fired if I set the value via javascript

Comment: what's the problem in `onchange` event? also I think you can't mutate HTML Element type object.

Comment: @KishoreBarik onchange only get fired on blur and not on keydown